# Attaching personalized documents in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have seen questions about document attachment in Marketing Cloud here, but we have a more complicated requirement. Our documents will have personalization, and they'll be different for all contacts, so we can't just tell the system to choose between 2-3 files and attach one. Documents will be created in Salesforce and sit under each record. Is it even possible to send them from Marketing Cloud and attach the right document for the right contact? We know that the feature needs to be enabled first, and we have read the documentation, but we don't see any solutions to our problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You have only two methods of attaching a file to an email in Marketing Cloud: fetching the file from FTP server, or fetching it from a URL. Each file can be shared publicly in Salesforce, and have it's details (including public URL) stored in the [ContentDistribution object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm). It is essential, depending on how sensitive the file is, to secure it, disallowing an open public access to it.  I will recommend you investigating whether you can use basic auth for the file, since this will be the only way in which you can provide the credentials in the [AttachFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm) function call:

```ampscript
%%=AttachFile('HTTP','https://user:pass@example.com/file.pdf','newFileName.pdf',false)=%%
```

Comment: There's also an additional cost for sends with attachments, IIRC.

Comment: Correct, @AdamSpriggs - FileAttachments are purchased in batches of 1000, and are consumed in addition to supermessages